# How to read SMS from iPhone Inbox programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, sms

After a review of the iOS documentation,  I can send SMS using MFMessageComposer in my application but I have not yet found a way for an application to be written such that it can programmatically process the content of an incoming SMS message within the iPhone platform. The idea would be for such an application to be running in the background and read sms from inbox and perform action automatically.

Comment: The security implications of a third-party app being able to access incoming text messages are pretty obvious, particularly doing so in the background, so it seems clear this will never be allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read SMS inbox programmatically in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470578/how-to-read-sms-inbox-programmatically-in-iphone)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible with the standard SDK.

You may be able to do this with a jailbroken phone?

Comment: Is there any update on this or we still can't access the SMS inbox programmatically?

Comment: Still can't do it. Suspect this won't change.

Comment: If i not upload that app on App store and my device is not Jailbreak than it will be possible or not ?