# How to read SMS inbox programmatically in iphone?

Tags: iphone, sms

How to read SMS inbox programmatically in iphone?

Comment: This is a very general question. You may want to research the topic a little more and ask a more specific question about any issues you encounter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iphone 4.0 = how to read SMS from IPhone Inbox Programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666192/iphone-4-0-how-to-read-sms-from-iphone-inbox-programatically)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with the official SDK.