# How to get iphone inbox all sms in my iphone application programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I want to get All SMS Text, sender number, date. in my iphone application and want to transfer from one iphone to another iphone ..is it possible to do it?

Comment: I certainly hope not.. I don't fancy random apps stealing all my messages!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone app reading sms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656723/iphone-app-reading-sms), [how to read SMS inbox programatically in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470578/how-to-read-sms-inbox-programatically-in-iphone), [How to get inbox all SMS on iphonse sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223232/how-to-get-inbox-all-sms-on-iphonse-sdk), .... Next search before you ask.

Comment: ultimately i want to transfer only all the sms from one iphone to another iphone...only sms is it possible through other way?

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible using Apple iOS SDK.