# Is it possible to access sms list in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to get the sms details from iPhone, that is count of sent and received messages and all messages that are stored in iphone device.

Comment: check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This question has [been asked and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470578/how-to-read-sms-inbox-programatically-in-iphone) here.  Please don't ask duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access these on a standard, non-jailbroken iPhone.

It is only possible when the phone is Jailbreaked. 
Once Jailbreaked, an application can open the SQLite database at

/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db and read the message table.

It contains, the date/time at which the message was received, the sender/recipient phone number and even the clear text of the message.

However this kind of app won't pass apple appstore approval process.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access the SMS db in iOS, If you try to do so it is against Apple's guidelines. However, if you are trying to develop an app for jail broken device you can access the SMS db.